# Hint needed on classifying finite groups with a certain property

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am asked to find all groups of order smaller than or equal to $30$ with the property that for any pair $x,y\in G$ we have
$$
x\in \langle y\rangle
$$
or 
$$
y\in \langle x\rangle
$$
I confess I don't have a great idea of where to start here. I imagine the Sylow theorems will come into play, but it doesn't seem like a good idea to start by enumerating such groups as this is labor intensive.

In short, what's the intuition for what this condition does and how do I use it to cut down how many groups there can be?

I think at least we can rule out cyclic groups of non prime order, since for the cases I checked, I can always pick two elements which are coprime but divide the order of the group, so that they generate subgroups which intersect trivially. For example, in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ we can choose $3$ and $4$, with $3\not\in \langle 4\rangle$ and $4\not\in \langle 3\rangle$. I have not however formalized this.

Any hints on perhaps a higher brow way to move forward would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A group $G$ with this property is a $p$-group. If not, then there are two coprime primes $p$ and $q$ dividing $|G|$, so that there exist elements $x$ and $y$ with order $p$ and $q$ by Cauchy's Theorem. Because $p$ and $q$ are coprime, this is not possible, as you have shown. $x\in \langle y\rangle $, or $y\in \langle x\rangle $ would mean, either $x=y^k$ or $y=x^r$ for some integers $r,k$. But $y^k$ cannot have order $p$, and $x^r$ cannot have order $q$. There are not too many $p$-groups of order $n\le 30$.